# Activating windows 10 home

Tags: windows-10

I have a genuine copy of windows 7 home basic. I downloaded ISO file of windows 10 from Microsoft website using other computer and copied the file from that computer to CD.If I install this ISO file,can I activate it using windows 7 genuine versions key.if not how can I make my windows 10 genuine ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions like this are better asked on Super User.

Answer (score 0):

Install Windows 7 and update from within W7

Comment: He already has Windows 7 installed.